# Call Thread.wait()

Tags: android, multithreading, handler, android-runonuithread

I need to make `currentThread` wait when do some operations in `UiThread` and then in `UiThread` call `currentThread().notify()` . I was trying this code

```
Handler uiHandler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
uiHandler.post(new Runnable() {
     @Override
     public void run() {
         try {
             currentThread().wait();
         } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
         }
        AlertDialog.Builder facultyChooser = new AlertDialog.Builder(ctx);
        facultyChooser.setTitle("choose")
                .setCancelable(false)
                .setItems(arr, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
                        currentThread().notify();
                    }
                })
                 .create()
                 .show();
         }
     });
}
```

but got `java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException: object not locked by thread before wait()` exception. Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code:

```
final Thread CURRENT_THREAD = currentThread();
Handler uiHandler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
uiHandler.post(new Runnable() {
     @Override
     public void run() {
        AlertDialog.Builder facultyChooser = new AlertDialog.Builder(ctx);
        facultyChooser.setTitle("choose")
                .setCancelable(false)
                .setItems(arr, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
                        synchronized(CURRENT_THREAD) {
                            CURRENT_THREAD.notify();
                        }
                    }
                })
                 .create()
                 .show();
         }
     });
}
synchronized(CURRENT_THREAD) {
      try {
          CURRENT_THREAD.notify();
      } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
      }
}
```